# 'slashbox.sty' not found

Tags: errors, auxiliary-files, latexit

I am not the best when it comes to working with programs like LaTeX and I am unable to open a `.tex` document, or rather 'LaTeX it' since it keeps coming up with this error.  I have downloaded `slashbox.sty`, but I am not sure where to put it so that LaTeXiT can use it.  Where should it go?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

[How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Basically, you can open a tex file with a text editor such as Apple TextEdit, notepad (Windows) or gedit (Gnome) for instance.

You can "LaTeX it" with the command `pdflatex` within an Apple Terminal or after typing `cmd` in the Windows start menu. Check out the FAQ of your LaTeX distro.

[LaTeX begin](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/)

hth

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I have a .tex file I'd like to run so I can see it in pdf form, but I can't since when I try to use LaTeXiT an error comes up as above.  Are you saying that by opening slashbox.sty in TextEdit I could get this to run?

Comment: no, that was not the statement. at the begin, you should read a little bit instead of guessing. for instance, you are coding within a tex file (at the begin) and not within a sty file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder inside your TeX home directory. You can find this directory typing this in your console:

`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`

Then, inside the directory that your console echoed create a folder that holds your `.sty`.

I think you should look at this question: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is rather a comment than an answer and should be converted to a comment by a moderator.